# Suspcicious pointer conversion warning

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, compiler-warnings, mplab-c18

I'm compiling my C code using Microchip's C18 compiler. I'm getting a warning `[2054] suspicious pointer conversion` in this code:

```
unsigned char ENC_MAADR1 = 0x65;
unsigned char ENC_ReadRegister(unsigned char address);
// ...
puts(ENC_ReadRegister(ENC_MAADR1)); // <-- warning on this line
```

What does this warning mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`puts` requires `const char*`, you are delivering `unsigned char`, not even a pointer.

From [here](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/puts.3.asp):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int puts(const char *s);
```

The `puts()` function writes the string pointed to by `s` to standard output stream stdout and appends a newline character to the output. The string's terminating null character is not written.

Use `putc(int c, FILE* stream)` instead... 
See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putc/) for a reference.

Thank you for the annotations!!

Comment: So what would a correct code look like? My pointers knowledge is bad.